# How to update API Level React native?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm getting to know react native and I need to update my API Level version and I have some doubts about how I can do it the right way.
This is my build.granle file:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
}
```

How could I upgrade to API Level 31 version? Would it just change the values ​​that today are "30" to "31"?

Comment: You can just update `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` from 30 to 31

Comment: @Ilnur Thank you very much for replying. buildToolsVersion would have any relation with the versions of compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?